# CRS is UTM 51, coordinates are shown in meters, show same coordinates as lat long as well?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, display, philippines

We are working with a CRS of UTM 51N, the Philippines. The coordinates under cursor are shown as metric values. Clients however like so see the Latitude Longitude values when they move the cursor.

Is there a way to display the cursor position in Latitude Longitude as well?

Answer (score 2):

for QGIS 1.9.0
Enable "on the fly projection" in `File -> Project Properties` and select CRS

WGS 84, EPSG:4326. This will display coords in Lon/Lat

[image: project props]